# ES6 modules in Gulp

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, gulp, es6-modules

I'm trying to make the boilerplate for frontend development based on GULP. As you can see in the code I've added gulp-babel task, but unfortunately ES6 modules (import, export) aren't working. What should I add to my code to solve this problem?

I read that I should use webpack for these purposes, so what should I do to integrate GULP with webpack

Thank you!

```
/*JS For Development*/
        gulp.task('js', function () {
          return gulp.src([
            'app/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
            'app/js/common.js',
          ])
              .pipe(concat('scripts.js'))
              .pipe(babel({
                presets: ['env']
              }))
              .pipe(gulp.dest('app/js'))
              .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
        });


gulp.task('browser-sync', function () {
  browserSync({
    server: {
      baseDir: 'app'
    },
    notify: false,
    // open: true,
    // tunnel: "gulp-boilerplate"
    // Demonstration page: http://gulp-boilerplate.localtunnel.me
  })
});


/*Styles For Development*/
gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src('app/scss/**/*.scss')
      .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'expanded'}).on("error", notify.onError()))
      .pipe(autoprefixer(['last 15 versions']))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
      .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});        

gulp.task('imagemin', function () {
  return gulp.src('app/img/**/*')
      .pipe(cache(imagemin()))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/img'));
});    

gulp.task('watch', ['sass', 'js', 'browser-sync'], function () {
  gulp.watch('app/scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
  gulp.watch(['libs/**/*.js', 'app/js/common.js'], ['js']);
  gulp.watch('app/*.html', browserSync.reload);
});    

gulp.task('build', ['removeDist', 'imagemin'], function () {

  var buildHtml = gulp.src([
    'app/*.html',
    'app/.htaccess',
  ]).pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));

  var buildCss = gulp.src([
    'app/css/main.css'
  ])
      .pipe(cleanCSS())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'));

  var buildFonts = gulp.src([
    'app/fonts/**/*'
  ]).pipe(gulp.dest('dist/fonts'));

  var buildJs = gulp.src([
    'app/js/scripts.js',
  ])
      .pipe(uglify())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));

});    

gulp.task('removeDist', function () {
  return del.sync('dist');
});    

gulp.task('clearCache', function () {
  return cache.clearAll();
});   

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove any import export, and put it all in a file called `common.js`. Gulp code:

```
const tpath = { publicJS:[
'src/public/javascripts/utils/common.js', 
'src/public/javascripts/*.js']
}
```

If the utils import stuff, add that path should be first in the array. Code:

```
const concatJS = ()=> src(tpath.src.publicJS)
.pipe(babel())
.pipe(concat('index.js'))
.pipe(uglify())
.pipe(dest(tpath.dest.publicJS));
```

Then in the **index.html** or the pre rendered files add `<script src='index.js'></script>`